# Save HTML DOM to Server

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to develop a site where one can enter into an editor mode (with the following javascript) and change the DOM.

```
        document.body.contentEditable = "true";
        document.designMode = "on"; void 0;
```

I want to submit the entire HTML DOM when the user clicks a "save changes" button (via html form), and then have PHP load those changes when the Site is refreshed.

Is this possible? I am new to PHP, so I don't know if this is the right way to go.

Comment: thought about one of the ' web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG editors"  such as tinymce or cfkeditor

Comment: Sounds like it is possible. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most browsers now support the outerHTML on the DOM but to play it safe you should be able to do `var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;`

You are now free to send markup via AJAX or any other way you wish to your server. However you should note if you don't take the necessary steps the Save button will also be included in `markup`.

It might be better to split your GUI into a DIV and your content into a DIV. Then just send the content separately.